# How to add array of objects to a newly created object with a hasMany relationship in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Take the following example:

```
//Parent object:
App.Parent = DS.Model.extend({
children: DS.hasMany('child');
name: DS.attr('string');
});

//Child object:
App.Child = DS.Model.extend({
parent: DS.belongsTo('App.Parent');
name: DS.attr('string');
});
```

I'm trying to create a new parent object with many children with the following:

```
var child1 = App.Child.createRecord({
name: "Test"
});

var child2 = App.Child.createRecord({
name: "Test2"
});

var newChildrenArray = [];
newChildrenArray.pushObject(child1);
newChildrenArray.pushObject(child2);

var parent = App.Parent.createRecord({
children: newChildrenArray,
name: "Hello :-)"
});
```

I can access parent.get('children') and access the childs names if I loop through with an alert. But in my handlebars templates, the children don't appear beneath the parents like they do for my parent and children FIXTURES. **Do I need to tell my template to re-render somehow, or is the template not loading the hasMany association, or am I creating the relationship wrong?**

I'm on the latest versions of Ember, Ember-Data, Handlebars etc, though have tried other versions to no avail so I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tried all manner of ways of getting my array onto the 'children' property of the parent object, but I stumbled across this in a pull request code snippet on Github and it's now working.

I guess my array was the wrong type for the parent object property, I still don't know how I'd create a seperate array to later pass to the object, but pushing directly onto it works!

```
var child1 = App.Child.createRecord({
name: "Test"
});

var child2 = App.Child.createRecord({
name: "Test2"
});

/*var newChildrenArray = [];
newChildrenArray.pushObject(child1);
newChildrenArray.pushObject(child2);*/

var parent = App.Parent.createRecord({
name: "Hello :-)"
});    

parent.get('children').pushObject(child1);
parent.get('children').pushObject(child2);
```